# Counting the frequency of target element in an unsorted array using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, divide-and-conquer, computation-theory

Suppose I have an unsorted array `A` of `n` integers and an integer `b`. I want to write an algorithm to compute the frequency of `b` in `A` (i.e., count the number of times `b` appears in `A`) using divide and conquer.

Here is a recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm to count the frequency of `b` in the array `A`:

1. Divide the array `A` into two sub-arrays: `left half` and `right half`.
2. Recursively count the frequency of `b` in `left half` of `A` and in `right half` of `A`.
3. Combine the results from step 2: the frequency of `b` in `A` is equal to the sum of the frequency of `b` in `left half` and the frequency of `b` in `right half`.
4. If the length of the array `A` is 1, return 1 if `A[0]` equals `b`, otherwise return 0.

The recurrence relation of the algorithm is T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1), where O(1) is the time to divide the array and combine the results. The solution of the recurrence is T(n) = O(n), so the time complexity of the algorithm is O(n).

This is because each recursive call divides the array into two sub-arrays of equal size, and each element is visited once at the bottom level of the recursion. Therefore, the algorithm visits each element of the array once, leading to a linear time complexity.

Correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: Because you are successively dividing the array into two parts, I believe, the Time Complexity is O(2^n) not O(n)

Comment: Pen and paper showed me that you split O(n) times and merge O(n) times. since everything else costs nothing (according to your description), that leads to O(n) total time.

Comment: Why use divide and conquer? You cannot get better than O(n) in an unsorted array and a linear search would avoid all the overhead of split, merge and the recursion.

Comment: @itprorh66 That's incorrect. The complexity is indeed O(n). You can't just hand-wave and say "You're splitting successively". You have to solve the actual recurrence relation.

Comment: @cadolphs returning 1 if the element is b at the leaf node of the tree is O(1) and I'm 100% sure about it, but do you agree that when we go all the way up to combine the solution, it is still done in O(1)? Because if that's true, then T(n) is indeed O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Let's just use concrete elements and do the math. The constant step during the splitting is O(1) so let's call it `c` and the constant step at the very end (Returning 1 or 0 for length 1 array) is just one step.

So then:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + c
T(1) = 1
```

We make the educated guess (or *ansatz*, if you want to use fancy language) that `T(n) = a*n + b`, i.e., a linear function. Let's plug that into the relations:

```
T(n) = a*n + b = 2 * (a*n/2 + b) + c
```

from which it follows after a bit of basic math that `b = -c`.

Next, we plug the ansatz into the base case:

```
T(1) = a*1 + b = a + b = 1
```

from which we can deduce that `a = 1 - b = 1 + c`.

So there! We solved for `a` and `b` without making a mess and indeed we have

```
T(n) = (1 + c) * n - c
```

which is indeed `O(n)`.

Note that this is the "pedestrian" way. If we're not interested in the actual coefficients a and b but really just in the complexity, we can be more efficient like so:

T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(1) = 4 T(n/4) + 2 * O(1) + O(1) =  ...
= 2^k T(1) + 2^(k-1) O(1) + 2^(k-2) O(1) ... + O(1)
= 2^k O(1) + 2^(k-1) O(1) + ...

where k = log_2(n).
Summing up all those precoefficients then we get roughly

T(n) = 2^(k+1) O(1) = 2 * n * O(1) = O(n)